# Power BI- Add leading zeros to number column that contain letters

Tags: sql, powerbi, transform, powerbi-desktop

I am using a table from an excel file which has a TEXT column "Service Code".

When I upload the data into Power BI, it automatically changes the field type to number and removes leading zeros. For Example, "000230" becomes "230", and "010000" becomes "10000".  I created a custom column and used = Number.ToText([#"Service Code"],"000000). This worked as all values in the column are 6 digits long, however, a few of them have a letter at the end which is causing error. For example,10014A or 10017Z. Is there a way to do this without causing error?

| Service Code | Custom | Desired output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 230 | 000230 | 000230 |
| 10000 | 010000 | 010000 |
| 10014A | Error | 10014A |
| 10017Z | Error | 10017Z |

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Custom Column from Examples" feature in PowerQuery and typed in the first two required values.

[image]

It created this formula:

```
Text.PadStart(Text.From([orig], "en-US"), 6, "0")
```